# Can I read a file(.txt) in static object? C++

Tags: c++, file, io, static, initialization

I have an static object.
File reading code is placed in that object's constructor.
Is this right or correct code?
Do this code have any problems?

A.hpp

```
Class A
{
public:
    A();

private:
    static A someA;
}
```

A.cpp

```
A A:someA;

A:A()
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("example.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allmost using static is a bad thing. If you must have something that is permanent in your apps you should use the "singleton" design pattern.

Having a reference of some class in himself should be made with a pointer and is use for example in a chained list.

For standard use of class  you do this after the description of your class

```
int  main( int argc, char**argv )
     {
       A Myclass           (   ) ;
       MyClass.DoSomething (   ) ;
       return              ( 0 ) ;
     }
```

Comment: I don't think singleton is relevant here.

Comment: Sorry. What is the chained list?

Comment: Chained list = [Linked-list] (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/180545/linked-list-class-in-c)